# Show dicount Price in magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento-2.2.5, special-price

How to show discount in percentage in product listing and product details section in magento 2.2.5 Like this

[image]

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code and modify it according to your requirement.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Anshu_Custom::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span>
    <?php 
    $item = $block->getSaleableItem();
    $_savePercent = 100 - round(((float)$item->getFinalPrice() / (float)$item->getPrice()) * 100); 
    echo $_savePercent . '% off';
    ?>
    </span>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Anshu Mishra, you save my day. It works for me. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Anshu Mishra, thank you for your help, this solution helps me a lot. One more thing I want to know that if I want to show the price like this for the **Configurable Product** in listing page, how can I do that? This type of pricing condition is shown in configurable product details section, but not showing in listing portion. In this listing section simple product showing this type of changes in pricing. **So I want to show this type of pricing condition for Configurable Product** also. Please help me, how can I do that. Thank you.